# Use PHP to post an entire mySQL command

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create my own query form, so that I can create a table in my DB, update data, select data, and so on. I have a file test.php with the form on which I will type my commands in a textarea. It will send my query to submitquery.php which contains the exact following:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"$_POST['myquery']");


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

this is the code I have in test.php:

```
<form action="submitquery.php" method="post">
<textarea name="myquery" id="myquery"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

but when I submit, I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /public_html/admin/submitquery.php on line 9"

I'm not that great with PHP, I'm a very basic beginner. Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this..

```
<?php
$query=$_POST['myquery'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Well .. coming to your example.. What if i typed `DROP TABLE yourtablename;` ? You will lose all your table information.

You need to check for SQL Injections... It's highly recommended to use **`Prepared Statements`** on PDO rather than doing like this.

Answer (score 0):

try below or remove ""

```
$sql = $_POST['myquery'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```